# How to make one computer assign tasks to another

Tags: c#, ubuntu-12.04, cluster-computing

I have a Beowulf cluster running Ubuntu 12.04LTS and am trying to set it up so I have a program running on the master where essentially I can ask it a question (for example, 8-2), it sends it to a predetermined node, that node receives and answer's the question, and sends the answer back to the master which then displays the answer. I know this sounds completely overly complicated and in the case of a math problem as simple as that it would be faster to just have the master answer it (or do it in my head...) but it's more of a proof-of-concept that I will build a lot more on in the future.

I already have MPI and SSH and all that jazz to make the cluster work with parallel problems, so if I can use them in any way that would be great, but I'm fine with installing new software as well.

I'm writing the program in C# and I'm very new to that language (as in, under a week new), so please just have patience with me because I'm probably not going to understand right away.

Any help provided will be much appreciated, thanks a bunch!

-Eric

Comment: How do you plan to use C# on linux? Are you using mono? Also, I'm not really sure what your asking about?

Comment: Yes, I plan to use mono, and what I'm trying to figure out is how to get a computer to send a message in a sense, to another computer, have a program on that computer interpret it, and then have it send a message back with the answer.

Comment: Since I'm so new to the language, if you think it would be easier to code this in another language I can just decide to code it in that instead, this is a personal project so there's no time restraint.

Comment: MPI and SSH are really all you need and if your using mono I don't see any problems with using C#. There are a couple of libraries out there for using MPI from C#.